# How to use local system fonts with wkhtml2pdf and pre tags

Tags: css, fonts

I'm using wkhtml2pdf and it looks like the renderer won't apply CSS font overrides **from local fonts** anywhere. It seems no matter what, wkhtml2pdf is using the default font, **unless the font is explicitly @import()ed**.

For the most part I'm OK with just a single font for the document, but it's annoying for code snippets when it doesn't render in a proportional font. I have font overrides for `<pre>` (and `<pre><code>`) like this:

```css
pre, pre > code {
   font-family: monospace;
}
```

I've also tried explicit fonts like `Consolas`, `Menlo` etc. which also doesn't work.

Here's what this looks like in the PDF:

[image]

As you can see the code block does not reflect the font change and renders in the document font, not monospace (or whatever other *built-in* font I might specify). Rendering the same in modern Chromium browsers renders the alternate font correctly.

I can get this to work however by use `@import()` and explicitly importing a Web font:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Code+Pro:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&display=swap');
```

And then referencing that font in the CSS:

```css
pre, pre > code {
   font-family: "Source Code Pro", monospace;
}
```

While that works using Web fonts isn't an ideal scenario as it requires Web access.

Two questions:

1. Is there a way to get wkhtml2pdf to work with built-in fonts in CSS styles? If so how do these need to be imported
2. Why is `monospace` which should be totally generic not working in this case?

Comment: Using `monospace` font works fine for me, I'm using current stable version `0.12.6` on Windows 10. Are you maybe using an older version? See .exe file properties -> Details -> File version. Here is my HTML source: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAZfC.png and this is what wkhtml2pdf produces from it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aqpf.png. The only other font stuff in the page is `body { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial Unicode MS; }` in a `<style>` tag on top. No custom or downloaded fonts. I tried it also with your `pre, pre > code { font-family: monospace; }` applied and that also works.

Comment: Hmm... I'm on latest and it definitely doesn't work. I tried with some very simple docs, but my base font list is multiple fonts. It seems that font inheritance is not working for me in any way unless I use a downloaded font. On Windows in my case.